# Best way to check selected weapon and draw without field name duplication

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Hi everyone I am making a simple Libgdx game on Android that involves touching the screen and hitting things.  However I have came across a slight problem.  I have a small selection of weapons to choose from but I don't know what the best way is to actually draw/access the selected weapons.  They are all inherited from a basic weapon class.  Right now I have a normal hammer class and a fast hammer class which extends hammer.

The fast hammer has some special methods and swings faster. When I just instantiate the classes I want to test it works fine.  However I want to do a check to see which hammer has been selected beforehand and then access it and draw it. I can't think of a very elegant way to do this other than a whole mass of if statements.

I originally tried giving a check variable an int.  Then If int 1 then hammer = new normalhammer(); else if int 2 then hammer = new fasthammer();  but this clearly won't work because my hammer variable is assigned to the normalhammer class i.e. Hammer hammer;  What is the best way to do this thanks.

```
Hammer hammer;
FastHammer hammer;//this obviously won't work because duplicate names

if(selected==1){//this was the plan but again won't work because duplication

            hammer = new Hammer();
        }

        else if (selected==2){
            hammer = new FastHammer();

        }

hammerframe = hammer.HammerAnimation.getKeyFrame(hammer.hammerTime+=delta, false);
  //then accessing the class variables won't work because again hammer is a duplicate field.  I basically want to check what the check int is and then set hammer to the right class based on that int and the rest of the code will automatically retrieve what I need.  Is this possible?
```

Comment: This is not irrelevant to the question but stop creating objects inside the main loop of the game ,GC is evil!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's how I would do it.

- Make all your weapon classes implement some interface/superclass that will help with rendering
- Keep an "armory" of weapon objects, one for each weapon type
- When the player selects a weapon, set the representative existing object into a "current weapon" variable
- For rendering, use the existing "current weapon" variable

Then you don't need to deal with the different types in the renderer - it's abstracted behind the interface!

Comment: Thanks.  what would you use for the armory? A linked list?

Comment: Probably just an array. Set the appropriate entry into the selected weapon variable when the user clicks in your weapon selection place.